# Unable to mark as duplicate as search is not returning results

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, search

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209810/add-glob-to-gitignore) about adding `#.#` to gitignore. Then I came across [a duplicate of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902446/how-can-i-add-pattern-that-start-with-hash-to-gitignore). I tried to flag it as duplicate, but the search returned

> "Your search returned no matches; please try a different search"?

What's happening there? Why is search not returning the original question?

Comment: I can get search results up on both questions. However, whilst those two questions are indeed duplicates, they are both over 2 years old so there would be little point in closing the questions now.

Comment: Why do you need to use a search? You can just paste the URL into the input field of the duplicate question box.

Comment: @worldofjr closing as duplicates (or closing in general) is always useful regardless of age.  The 2nd question he linked here doesn't have an answer, so if a user with the same problem found that question, how would they know there is another question with the solution?  The point is, judge all posts as if they were asked today.  If a question was on-topic when asked, but off-topic now, vote to close.  If you find a duplicate 3 years later, vote to close.  Old unanswered question do little good.

Comment: @Barmar +1, by pasting the URL at least now I received a meaningful message _"That question has no accepted or upvoted answers"_, instead of just no matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's due to the `#*`, because these two symbols are interpreted to find something.

> `*` : something between what you search.

For instance, if you are searching for `The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List` and you write `The Definitive *
List` you will have this:

[image: res <code>The Definitive * List</code>]

> So if you write: `add #*# glob to .gitignore?`
>   your result will be:

[image: res <code>add #*# glob to .gitignore?</code>]

> but if you write `add ## glob to .gitignore?` your result will be:

[image: res <code>add ## glob to .gitignore?</code>]